# Can I have JSTL tags inside the body of <jsp:include> tag

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I am trying to include a file with dynamic parameters. The parameters come from an array.

This is the code I wrote:

```
<jsp:include page="${jspName}">
    <c:if test="${paramList != null}">
        <c:forEach var="paramPair" items="${paramList().getList()}">
            <jsp:param name="${paramPair.getName()}" value="${paramPair.getValue()"/> 
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</jsp:include>
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes.
```

Can someone please help me figure out how I can send these parameters dynamically to the file from the parameter array?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** include any expression or jstl tags inside the body of a `<jsp:include>` tag, you can only have `<jsp:param>` tags inside the body, as per the [JSP documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828).

To understand your requirement better, please answer this question:
Since the parameter names are also dynamic, how do you suppose to get these parameters inside the jsp file represented by `${jspName}`?

---

**Still here are few of my suggestions:**
I would suggest rethink of the design and using the include directive (`<%@ include file="myJsp.jsp" %>`) instead of the standard action.

Or

If you want to use `<jsp:include>` then you do any of the following:

- Pass two `<jsp:param>`; one with a comma-separated `name` list (`name1,name2,name3`) and other with a comma-separated `value` list (`value1`,`value2`,`value3`). In your inlcuded jsp `${jspName}`, do some simple string manipulation to get the name and values.

  ```
  <c:set name="nameList" value="" /> 
  <c:set name="valueList" value="" /> 

  <c:if test="${paramList != null}">
      <c:forEach var="paramPair" items="${paramList().getList()}">
          <c:set name="nameList">${nameList},${paramPair.getName()},</c:set>
          <c:set name="valueList">${valueList},${paramPair.getValue()},</c:set>
      </c:forEach>
  </c:if>

  <jsp:include page="${jspName}">
      <jsp:param name="nameListToBePassed" value="${nameList}" />
      <jsp:param name="valueListToBePassed" value="${valueList}" />
  </jsp:include>
  ```
- Pass one `<jsp:param>` with a comma-separated `nameValue` list like `[name1=value1,name2=value2,name3=value3]`.

  ```
  <c:set name="nameValueList" value="" />

  <c:if test="${paramList != null}">
      <c:forEach var="paramPair" items="${paramList().getList()}">
          <c:set name="nameValueList">${nameValueList},${paramPair.getName()}=${paramPair.getValue()},</c:set>
      </c:forEach>
  </c:if>

  <jsp:include page="${jspName}">
      <jsp:param name="nameValueListToBePassed" value="${nameValueList}" />
  </jsp:include>
  ```

Hope this gives some direction.